# @ConfigurationProperties don't work in test in Spring Boot 2.4.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-boot-2, configurationproperties

I have an application that works fine in Spring Boot 2.3.8 but the `@RestClientTest`s fails with 2.4.2 because the test objects can not be instantiated because there's no bean of the `@ConfigurationProperties` (which is created by the `@TestConfiguration`).

How do I have to change my code so it works with 2.4.x?

Code is:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tyntec.routetest.dsidr")
@Data
@Validated
public class DynamicSenderIdReplacementClientConfiguration {

  @NotBlank
  private String baseUrl;
  @NotBlank
  private String dsidrPath;
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DynamicSenderIdReplacementClient {

  private final DynamicSenderIdReplacementClientConfiguration configuration;
}

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@RestClientTest(DynamicSenderIdReplacementClient.class)
@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)
class DynamicSenderIdReplacementClientWebTest {

  @Autowired
  private DynamicSenderIdReplacementClient cut;

  @TestConfiguration
  static class testConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DynamicSenderIdReplacementClientConfiguration provideConfig() {
      return new DynamicSenderIdReplacementClientConfiguration() {
        {
          setBaseUrl(BASE_URL);
          setDsidrPath(DSIDR_PATH);
        }
      };
    }
  }
```

This works in 2.3.8 but fails in 2.4.2 with

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.tyntec.routetesting.client.itest.clients.DynamicSenderIdReplacementClientConfiguration' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Comment: Piecing things together from the snippets above, your example works fine for me with Spring Boot 2.4.1 with the `DynamicSenderIdReplacementClientConfiguration` bean defined in `testConfiguration` being injected into `DynamicSenderIdReplacementClient`. Can you update your question with a complete and minimal example that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, `@RestClientTest` works as advertised and inhibits the beans in `@TestConfiguration`:

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead
> apply only configuration relevant to rest client tests (i.e. Jackson
> or GSON auto-configuration and `@JsonComponent` beans, but not regular
> `@Component` beans).

Using `@Import` helps.

```
@RestClientTest(DynamicSenderIdReplacementClient.class)
@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)
@Import(DynamicSenderIdReplacementClientWebTest.testConfiguration.class)
class DynamicSenderIdReplacementClientWebTest {
```